# Bounding rect to the complex form?

Tags: qt, shapes

The subjects of our project is making a program who simulate a Fusion.

We have some problem with the colliding with our classe Fusion. We want to make a shape complex for our colliding.

[printScreenFusionProgramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuOB5.png)

Our shape is two circle near each other and we dont want to have a bounding rect but shape "complex"...

this is our Fusion class

```
Fusion::Fusion(int x, int y)
{
 this->setPos(x, y);
}

void Fusion::shape(){
//...
}

 void Fusion::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
  {

   //set the color
   QBrush brushColor(QColor(Qt::blue));
   painter->setBrush(brushColor);
   painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::blue));
   painter->drawEllipse(0,0,40,40);
   painter->drawEllipse(-20,-20,40,40);
  }

  void Fusion::doCollision()
  {
    // get a new position

    // change the angle with randomness
    if(qrand() %1)
    {
        setRotation(rotation() + (180 + (qrand() % 10)));
    }
    else
    {
        setRotation(rotation() + (180 + (qrand() % -10)));
    }

    // check if the new position is in bounds
    QPointF newPoint = mapToParent(-(boundingRect().width()), -(boundingRect().width() + 2));

    if(!scene()->sceneRect().contains((newPoint)))
    {
        // move back in bounds
        newPoint = mapToParent(0,0);
    }
    else
    {
        // set the new position
        setPos(newPoint);
    }
}

void Fusion::advance(int step)
{
  if(!step) return;

  if(!scene()->collidingItems(this).isEmpty())
  {
    doCollision();
  }

 setPos(mapToParent(0, -1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reimplement the "shape" method for your graphics items to return the actual shape of your object. You can return any shape you want in a QPainterPath, and Qt will use that for collision detection.

Comment: Hi, thank u for you help!!! But with this we are a screenbug look -> [bugScreen](http://i.imgur.com/P5ib3lL.png). Idk if its because the shape()... do have any idea for this bug ?

Comment: The picture indicates that either your boundingRect or your shape function isn't accurate, or that you've failed to call prepareGeometryChange before  some operations that affect the results of those methods. When that happens, you see drawing artifacts because the old region doesn't get properly cleared.